# BelongsToMany create operation with Pivot Data - PHP Lighthouse Laravel

Tags: laravel, graphql, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-lighthouse

In PHP Lighthouse you can have `ManyToMany` relationships. Using nested operations allows you to create say an `Author`, `Post` and connect them using a pivot table `post_author` ALL in one operation.

Lighthouse also allows you to store data in the pivot table. In their docs, they give an example of how to `connect` a record with some pivot table data. There is no example available on how to do a `create` operation with extra pivot table data.

Docs pivot data `update` operation: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/nested-mutations.html#storing-pivot-data

```
type Mutation {
  createPost(input: CreatePostInput! @spread): Post @create
}

input CreatePostInput {
  title: String!
  authors: CreateAuthorBelongsToMany
}

input CreateAuthorBelongsToMany {
  create: [CreateAuthorInput!]
}

input CreateAuthorInput {
  name: String!
  #contribution_percentage: Int! #Pivot table column
}

#query:

mutation {
  createPost(
    input: {
      title: "My new Post"
      authors: {
        create: [{ name: "Herbert", contribution_percentage: 50 }]
      }
    }
  ) {
    id
    authors {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I tried fiddling with the scheme to "guess" the correct scheme, to no avail.

My objective is:  Create an `Author`, `Post`, and connect them using a `post_author` pivot table WITH `extra pivot data`, ALL in one operation.